# How to obtain position in file (byte-position) from java scanner?

Tags: java, file, position, java.util.scanner

How to obtain a position in file (byte-position) from the java scanner?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file"));
scanner.useDelimiter("abc");
scanner.hasNext();
String result = scanner.next();
```

and now: how to get the position of result in file (in bytes)?

Using scanner.match().start() is not the answer, because it gives the position within internal buffer.

Answer (score 5):

Its possibe using RandomAccessFile..  try this..

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class RandomFileAccessExample 
{
    RandomFileAccessExample() throws IOException
    {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("someTxtFile.txt", "r");
        System.out.println(file.getFilePointer());
        file.readLine();
        System.out.println(file.getFilePointer());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new RandomFileAccessExample();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, but with RandomAccessFile I can't use Regular Expressions in such a easy way as with Scanner...

Comment: thats right! but one way of doing is read all the lines, store it in a string and use regEx in the string.. I know! this sounds very bad! :)

Comment: java as such do not provide tokenizer with RandomAccessFile. What else can we do!? build up some logic. read line by line and tokenize it.!

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner` provides an abstraction over the underlying `Readable`, whose content need not necessarily come from a `File`. It doesn't directly support the kind of low-level query that you're looking for.

You may be able to compute this number by combining the internal buffer position according to the `Scanner` and the number of bytes read according to the `Readable`, but even this looks to be a tricky proposition. If an approximate location within a huge file is acceptable, then this may be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an approximate file position by using a custom FileInputStream to create the Scanner, like this:

```
final int [] aiPos = new int [1];
FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream( file ) {
   @Override
   public int read() throws IOException {
       aiPos[0]++;
       return super.read();
   }
   @Override
   public int read( byte [] b ) throws IOException {
       int iN = super.read( b );
       aiPos[0] += iN;
       return iN;
   }
   @Override
   public int read( byte [] b, int off, int len ) throws IOException {
       int iN = super.read( b, off, len );
       aiPos[0] += iN;
       return iN;
   }
};

Scanner scanner = new Scanner( fileinputstream );
```

This will give you a position accurate to within 8K or so, depending on the implementation of FileInputStream. This is useful for things like updating progress bars during a file parse, where
you don't need the exact position, just something reasonably close.